# Как в объект php положить функцию?

Tags: php, функции, объекты

В документации могу найти только классы, конструкторы.

```
class такой-то... {
    состоит из того-то...
}
```

Но я хочу просто используя `$obj = (object) ["ключ" => "значение"];` положить в "значение" функцию, но таким образом:

```
function printIt() {
    print "Ha-Ha";
}
$obj = (object) ["func" => printIt];
$obj->func();
```

Это не работает. Как правильно?

Comment: Правильно - использовать анонимные функции. http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = function printIt() { 
     print "Ha-Ha"; 
};
$obj = (object) ["func" => $a];
call_user_func($obj->func);
```

Comment: Ваш пример можно изменить так.

Comment: но ведь это не решает мой вопрос.

Comment: Ваш вопрос: как положить функцию в объект - в моем примере функция находится в объекте. Перефразируйте свой вопрос тогда.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '$obj' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: В моём примере функция тоже находится в объекте.

Comment: Вызвать функции замыкания как вы хотите нельзя. Можно использовать либо call_user_func(), либо вызвать метод Closure::call()

Comment: Исправил немного, скобки не нужны в $obj->func

Comment: 1: Вы некорректно создаете функцию (дважды пишите название.) 2: syntax error, unexpected '$obj' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: @ArtyomZinovyev я скопировала ваш же пример :) точки с запятой не хватало вроде бы.

Comment: нет :) У меня было: `function printIt() { }`, а у вас `$a = function printIt() { }`, вы даёте функции 2 имени